node js typegoose invalid type
I get an error with typegoose:
fdsaf
InvalidTypeError: "BaseModel.createdAt"'s Type is invalid! Type is: "undefined" [E009]
User model:
import { getModelForClass, pre, prop } from "@typegoose/typegoose";

@pre<User>("save", async function () {
  if (!this.isModified("password")) return;
  this.password = await hashPassword(this.password);
})
export class User extends BaseModel {
  @prop({ required: true })
  public login: string;

  @prop({ required: true })
  public password: string;

  @prop({ enum: Role, required: true })
  public role: Role;

  @prop({ required: true })
  public name: string;

  @prop({ required: true })
  public surname: string;

  public async checkPassword(candidatePassword: string): Promise<boolean> {
    return await verifyPassword(this.password, candidatePassword);
  }
}

And package.json:
{
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npx tsx src/index.ts",
    "start": "npm run build && npm run serve",
    "build": "npx tsc && npx tsc-alias -p tsconfig.json",
    "serve": "node ./dist/index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@typegoose/typegoose": "^12.3.0"
  }
}

People recommend add emitDecoratorMetadata to tscong.json, but it does not work in my case  Any ideas?
I tried to change node version and also add emitDecoratorMetadata param to tscong.json file.

As the error states, the problem is in Class BaseModel, property createdAt, please provide that class too. Aside from that please confirm what engine you are using (node, deno, bun, etc). Also make sure that tsconfig option experimentalDecorators is enabled as typegoose (and typescripts option emitDecoratorMetadata) does not use ES Decorators yet. If you still have problems, consider providing typegoose debug logs and / or a reproduction repository.
